# Minimal prime ideals of the ring of continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $X$ be a topological space. Are there any conditions on $X$ which guarantee that that the minimal prime ideals of $C(X)$, the ring of real-valued continuous functions on $X$, have a nice characterization?

Comment: In general, the space of minimal prime ideals is huge. See theorem 5.6 in this paper: https://www.math.hmc.edu/~henriksen/publications/1965_Henriksen_Jerison_The_space_of_minimal_prime_ideals_of_a_commutative_ring.pdf